# Problema al ejecutar ajax hacia php seguidas vecez

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

amigo tengo un problema al ejecutar un ajax n cantidad de veces se me topa el servidor y me tumba la pagina, podría esto ser parte de el servidor o de javascript.

el ajax es un ajax común,

```
$({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "Json",
  data: json,
  url: "busqueda.php",
  success:function(msg){
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo de tu codigo, estas usando un alert, cuando abre el Alert frena la execution del Javascript de la Pagina y eso debe hacer que se trave tu navegador.
Recomiendo que si es para log, usar console.log.

Otra cosa interesante que deberias haber, es hacer un check si ya tenes algun llamado a ese ajax para no hacer otro hasta que termine.